# Splits a string by number

Tags: python, word-wrap

I have just written a very simple function which splits a string by a given number. It works, but got flaws. It sometimes breaks a word apart, for example:

```
string = "He could not meet her in conversation"
number_of_lines = 5
result = (textwrap.fill(string, count(string, number_of_lines)))
print result

He could
not meet
her in c
onversat
ion
```

Please note it breaks the word "conversation." I need suggestions how to overcome this problem, or there is an inbuilt function for this task already available.

Here is the actual function:

```
import textwrap
import re

def count (s, no_of_lines):
    result = (textwrap.fill(s.upper(), 1))
    count = 1  
    while (len(re.split('[\n]', result)) != no_of_lines):
        count = count + 1
        result = (textwrap.fill(s.upper(), count))
    return count
```

Comment: split the string by whitespace and only add to a line if the next word fits on the line

Comment: Please provide the expected output for your example. Should it use 4 lines only, or should it split some other line in two to still get to 5?

Comment: @trincot, there is no strict rules about lines 4 and 5 both could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`break_long_words`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.TextWrapper.break_long_words) option of the [`TextWrapper` constructor](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.TextWrapper):

```
import textwrap
import re

# define a customised object with option set to not break long words
textwrap = textwrap.TextWrapper(break_long_words=False)

def count (s, no_of_lines):
    # set the width option instead of using a count
    textwrap.width = 1
    result = textwrap.fill(s.upper())
    while len(re.split('\n', result)) > no_of_lines:
        textwrap.width += 1
        result = textwrap.fill(s.upper())
    return textwrap.width

string = "He could not meet her in conversation"
number_of_lines = 5
textwrap.width = count(string, number_of_lines)
result = textwrap.fill(string)
print (result)
```

Output:

> He could
>   not meet
>   her in
>   conversation